# Swift best practice using view or image

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview

I have a table view, and I am going to have each cell display a "badge" more or less a round icon with a letter inside.

So should I style a uiview and put a label inside it or should I simply design it in PS/Sketch then just display it as a UIImageview?

Thanks

Comment: I'd say you should use the `UIView` approach since it gives you more flexibility and you won't need to create a new image every time you need to make a new badge. But this kind of question almost always comes down to what do _you_ find to be easier.

Comment: But is there any difference peformance wise?

Comment: Only if you are doing manipulation to the image. Such as applying tint, transformation, masking those kinds of things. But that will only slow things down when you do the initial manipulation and even then not a noticeable performance hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use UIView in such case because:

- If you round corners with `CALayer`, it will looks fine on all screens (@1x, @2x, @3x) and you don't need to have 3 images
- You can easy resize it
- You can easy customise it with shadow or any other effect to `CALayer`
- You can easy add extra button/label/anything

Comment: nope, except if you will use shadows on `CALayer` In that case I trying to rasterize layer